# react fetch javascript upload video nodejs multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, multer

I am uploading a video with fetch

```
    const formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', asset.name);
    formData.append('file', asset.file);

    fetch(generateUrl(`/asset/video?token=${getState().server.token}`), {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) return response.json().then(error => { throw new Error(error.message) });
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I am getting the file from a react ref `this.fileInput = React.createRef()`, the file value is `this.fileInput.current.files[0]` so `asset.file === this.fileInput.current.files[0]`

Then I am uploading it to my server

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({})

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/video', upload.single('file'), dataProvider.security.middleware('post_asset'), (req, res, next) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('test.mp4', req.file.buffer);
})
```

But I have an issue somewhere in the transfer and I can nit identify it.

The created file `test.mp4` is corrupted, original file is 540KB and `test.mp4` 750KB

With const upload = multer({ dest: '/Users/ajouve/Downloads/' }) I also have a 750KB file and corrupted

The `Content-Length` header is `540240` so the sent content should be ok

Comment: Did you try adding `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to your headers in fetch ?

Comment: fetch add it automatically, if I add it manually I have an error telling me that boundary is missing. This is what fetch generate `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary3Pj4dzoJJagAA16K`

Answer (score 0):

Multer is supposed to be writing the file for you, so this line

```
fs.writeFileSync('test.mp4', req.file.buffer);
```

shouldn't be there. Perhaps thats why you get bigger size, because of double writing.

So put destination back

```
const upload = multer({dest:"/Users/ajouve/Downloads/"})
```

Make the post return some 'ok' response.

I have almost the same setup here and the rest is fine.

```
dataProvider.security.middleware('post_asset')
```

I don't use that too, not sure what it does.